# Embedding date from variable to xpath contains() statement

Tags: ruby, xpath, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am constantly crashing Capybara/Poltergeist/PhantomJS combination when I try to pass quotes (single/double) around a variable into XPath statement that contains

```
contains(text(), ... )
```

This xpath works if I type it into for example FirePath

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[@class='date'][contains(text(), "14.8.2014" )]
```

Single and double quotes work when typed directly in FirePath. But I need to get that date from variable "date" and I haven't found a way to do that.

If I do this:

```
..[contains(text(), #{date.strftime("%e.%-m.%Y")})]
```

I get the date but without the quotes around it.

```
..[contains(text(), 14.8.2014 )]
```

I can get single quotes around the date if they are included in the strftime

```
..[contains(text(), #{date.strftime("'%e.%-m.%Y'")} )]
```

And it even looks correct in the PhantasmJS crash message

```
..[contains(text(), '14.8.2014' )]
```

But for some reason it still crashes on this find statement.

In addition I have tried escaping quotes but all I get is this kind of result:

```
..[contains(text(), \"14.8.2014\"  )]
```

Am I even solving the correct problem, am I doing this correctly but PhantomJS just can't handle it?

All help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried this also with removing 'contains' altogether and hardcoding 'Thu' for Thursday into strftime but this didn't make any difference.

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[@class='date'][text()= '#{date.strftime("to %e.%-m.%Y")']
```

Again if output is used in Firebug it works just fine.

**UPDATE2**

Below is full error message I get:

```
/home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:33:in `send': PhantomJS client died while processing {"name":"find","args":["xpath","//table[@class='calendar-one-week']/tbody/tr/td[@class='date'][text()='to 14.8.2014']/following-sibling::td[1]//li"]} (Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient)
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:270:in `command'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:53:in `find'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:114:in `find'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:118:in `find_xpath'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:107:in `find_xpath'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/query.rb:110:in `block in resolve_for'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:80:in `synchronize'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/query.rb:106:in `resolve_for'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:147:in `block in all'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:146:in `all'
from /home/thepanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@mech/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:675:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
from capytest.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

And the line causing the error:

```
session.all("//table[@class='calendar-one-week']/tbody/tr/td[@class='date'][text()= '#{date.strftime("to %e.%-m.%Y").to_s}']/following-sibling::td[1]//li"    )
```

Comment: have you tried `...[contains(text(), '#{date.strftime("%e.%-m.%Y")}' )]` with the single quotes outside of the interpolation?

Comment: Yes. It outputs it correctly but PhantomJS still crashes.

Comment: am i write that element in html you are trying to access is like `<td class="date">14.8.2014</td>` ?

Comment: It includes shorthand of the weekday as well. That's why 'contains'. Ie. "Wed 14.8.2014".

Comment: What do you mean by “crashing”? What’s the full error message, and what‘s the full line of code causing it?

Comment: @matt Added error message and line to question.

Comment: The `session.all(...)` line looks suspicious since the starting double quotes terminate before the date string. Have you tried something with triple double quotes `"""to %e.%-m.%Y"""`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert I think I have at some point. But I will doublecheck later today. I also have tried creating the whole xpath string before the .all call with concat but results were similar.

Comment: @MarcusRickert Nope, didn't make a difference. I also tried separating variable from beginning and end of the string still the same results. For some reason it doesn't know how to evaluate the statement.